# Order SQL records with same value by second criteria

Tags: sql, sql-order-by

I order some records by their value. If two records have the same value i want to order those two records by their date.
For example:

```
record1 34 1.1.2000
record2 26 3.4.2000
record3 26 2.4.2001
record4 76 1.5.2000
```

This should be ordered like this:

```
record4 76 1.5.2000
record1 34 1.5.2000
record3 26 2.4.2001
record2 26 3.4.2000
```

How can i manage this in SQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM myTable
ORDER BY Value, Date
```

Each of these can also have an ASC/DESC specifier:

```
SELECT * 
FROM myTable
ORDER BY Value ASC, Date DESC
```

Here is a link to MSDN, describing the syntax of the [`ORDER BY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188385.aspx) clause.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM records ORDER BY field1, field2
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the second order by column to the ORDER BY clause:

```
SELECT field1, field2, field3
FROM table
ORDER BY value, date
```